# Database Design for Storing Generic Filters on Notification Sources

Tags: database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

Suppose one would like to create (very) customizable notifications. That is, a user cannot only subscribe to a set of notification types to receive but the user can also filter on attributes of the notification source.

E.g. Consider an application with multiple entities:[image]

Now consider the following notification types:

| Notification type | Notification source |
| --- | --- |
| Task created | Task |
| Task changed | Task |
| Order created | Order |
| Order changed | Order |

The user wishes to subscribe to some of the notification types under a set of conditions. Some examples:

- The user wants to receive a notification when a task is created with a specific label
- The user wants to receive a notification when a task is changed with status "closed"
- The user wants to receive a notification when an order is created with price "100.000"

**How can one design a database model such that a user can subscribe to a notification type under a (generic) set of conditions?**

One idea could be as depicted in the ER diagram below. However no referential integrity is maintained and some sort of trick must be used to allow for many-to-many relationship filtering. Therefore, I feel like I should avoid this idea.

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm stuggle with same architecture problem.

Comment: @PatrickAcioli Nope, we decided to skip the feature for now